# Jenkins : Sending Build Trend Graph as email

Tags: email, graph, build, report, jenkins

Can jenkins send as email , the build trend graphs ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Email-ext Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) can send HTML e-mails. As the URL of the graph is known (for example, for the test trend graph the URL is: `http://[server]/job/[job-name]/test/trend`) it can be embedded into your e-mail with `<img>` tag like this:

```
<img src="${PROJECT_URL}test/trend" />
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me, as the image does not show up in the email.  In order to make this solution work one will have to make their Jenkins setup public so that the email client can download the image, otherwise, it would show up as a broken image in the email.

Comment: i just checked in my jenkins project build path /test/trend path is not available. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive ,there is no such plugin for Jenkins to send an email with trend graph of build. 
For advance mailing or report , you can try plugin [Email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)